# What is the biblical basis for Mary being the ark of the new covenant?

Tags: catholicism, biblical-basis, eastern-orthodox, virgin-mary, ark-of-the-covenant

Both Orthodox and Catholic Christians believe and affirm that the Blessed Virgin Mary is the ***ark of the new covenant***, but is there a scriptural basis for this and if so where do we see this in the Old or the New Testament?

Comment: See list of OT and NT parallels in [SolaGratia's answer](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/57306/10672).

Comment: I mean, does that symbolic language **need** biblical support? The ark contains the law (and other items full of symbolism), pregnant Mary "contains" baby Jesus. Is there any more to it?

Comment: @kutschkem Considering that many other Christians don't see there being any substantial parallels, yes. And even trivial questions can be asked about here.

Comment: I wish there were a better way to pull out out Sola Gratia's parallels into this page like we could on a wiki, I don't think this is a bad question, but I don't see much of a point of answering it when there's already the most awesome answer concerning Our Lady on the entire planet in that other post.  I guess you could just answer [because she is Holy](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/57306/10672)

Comment: Asking for the biblical basis assumes a model of authority already dissonant with the traditions you are asking about. Scripture is part of, but not the whole of, Holy Tradition. This is like asking for a driver to show you the fastest route but asking him not to shift past second gear. The Bible itself was compiled in, by, and for the Church, and so within Catholic and Orthodox perspectives, must also be read within the Church.