# In light of Romans 3:23, how do Catholics support their belief that Mary was without sin?

Tags: catholicism, sin, virgin-mary, romans

The Catholic Church says that Mary was sinless.  How do they reconcile this view with verses such as Romans 3:23?

> For there is no distinction: for all have sinned and fall short of the glory of God.  Romans 3:22b-23 (ESV)

This verse seems to clearly state that everyone sins.  There is no place in the Bible, to my knowledge, that states Mary as an exception.

Comment: You do realize that Catholics do not believe that the Word of God is confined to the Bible, yes?

Comment: And have you read [this possibly related question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/4362/what-is-the-biblical-basis-for-the-immaculate-conception)

Comment: @Matt Gutting Thank you, I didn't realize that it was called immaculate conception.

Comment: You're welcome! You've phrased the question in an important way, worth an upvote.